# Changing menu name after selecting item with bootstrap menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 Bootstrap dropdown menus where you can select an item:

```
<div class="btn-group onderdeelnaam">    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="onderdeel1"></button>    
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">    
        <li><a href="#" id="onderdeel1-1">onderdeel1-1</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#" id="onderdeel1-2">onderdeel1-2</a></li>    
    </ul>    
</div>  

<div class="btn-group onderdeelnaam">    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="onderdeel2"></button>    
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown1">    
        <li><a href="#" id="onderdeel2-1">onderdeel2</a></li>      
    </ul>    
</div>
```

When I click an `li` item the following script gets triggered and changes both the boxes to the same name.

```
$(function(){    
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){     
        $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());    
        $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());    
        $("button").append("<span class='caret'>");    
    });      
});
```

So it doesn't matter which one I select, both the dropdown menus get the same name of the item I selected. I have tried to experiment with the last script to make the change happen to only 1 of the menus, for example I've tried to change the `.dropdown-menu` class to the `id`, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to amend your code to use the `this` keyword to reference the element which was clicked. From there you can use `closest()` and `find()` to retrieve the related `button` element. Try this:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.btn').text($(this).text()).append("<span class='caret'>");
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ooj9n8m5/)

Comment: Thanks for your fast and working answer! Works like a charm now :)

Comment: I get: Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score